# How to POST an object to controller

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm having a difficulty passing my 'product' object to the controller. How can I do it? I'm not getting errors. The problem is that the 'product' object is null on my controller.

**html**:

```
<section th:each="menu : ${allMenus}">
<button
    <h1 th:text="${menu.name}"></h1>
</button>
<div>
    <div th:each="product : ${menu.productList}">
        <a data-toggle="modal" th:href="'#' + ${product.name} + 'Modal'">
            h5 th:text="${product.name}"></h5>
            <small th:text="${product.price} + '$'"></small>
            <p th:text="${product.description}"></p>
        </a>
    <div th:replace="/productModal :: productModal(product=${product})"></div>
</div>
</section>
```

Modal:

```
<div th:fragment="productModal(product)">
<div role="document">
    <form method="post" th:action="@{/addItemToCart}">
        <div th:each="topping : ${product.toppings}">
            <input type="checkbox" th:id="${topping} + ${product.id}" name="checkedToppings" th:value="${topping}" />
            <label th:for="${topping} + ${product.id}" th:text="${topping}"></label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Add to Shopping Cart</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

**controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addItemToCart", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addItemToCart(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product, @RequestParam("checkedToppings") List<String> toppings)
{
    //product is null;
    //checkedToppings are retrieved correctly

    return "redirect:/menu";
}
```

Comment: You need to include the relevant error messages or an example of how it is failing within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:
you don't post objects to controllers using HTML.

Details:
You will never be able to post a "product" object to your controller from an HTML page.
Instead,
you should send identifying information about the desired "product" to the controller,
perhaps a product-id or some other product-unique-identity-blammy.

Response to options in comments:
Hackers love hidden fields and JavaScript;
I recommend against using those for this situation.
I believe that you only have one option: identifying info.
This does not need to be a "real" product number.
You can generate a UUID and store a map in the choose one: (Servlet Session, Database, Application Session, somewhere else on the server) that maps from the UUID to the desired product.

Comment: So my options are:
1) Send identifying info
2) Multiple hidden inputs
3) Use JavaScript(maybe AJAX)

Comment: Shouldn't identifying information be sent with hidden inputs?

Comment: You can render it using a hidden input, but you don't want to use more than just an identifier hidden input.  Also, be sure to validate the input field before you use it on the server, because hackers will send any number of values using hidden inputs.

Comment: You can also render the identifier as the value of the selection item (if you are selecting a product from a selection element).  This uses no hidden fields, but you still have to validate because anything sent from the HTML page can be manipulated by a hacker.